# Where's my horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, I bought a horse in Whiterun because I needed to go Ivarstead and didn't want to go on foot. While in Ivarstead, I was arrested in an inn.

I paid my bounty and ended up in Riften, and my horse is no longer with me. I have no clue where it is now. Is still at Ivarstead or somewhere else?

Comment: Try fast travelling. This should cause your horse to arrive next to you.

Comment: Dude, Where's my horse?